# How to get props on recompose lifecycle without using `this`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle, recompose

I'm using `eslint-plugin-immutable` so I can't use `this` keyword (I can eslint-disable-line, but I don't want to), so I'm wondering if there is any way with `recompose` to access the props inside any of the mount lifecycle, without using the `this` keyword.

```
const enhance = compose(
  lifecycle({
    componentWillMount() {
      const { props } = this // throws eslint error
      console.log(this.props); // works, throws eslint error
    },
  }),
);
```

Comment: Why would eslint complain about *references* to `this`? You basically cannot get around `this` in JavaScript; it's fundamental to the object model.

Comment: Beucase of eslint-plugin-immutable, there is a rule called no-this

Comment: Well like I said, if you're working with JavaScript prototype code it's pretty hard to get around making references to `this`; it basically makes using such code impossible or at best pointless.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But that's not the point, just wanna know if it's possible or not. That doesn't mean I'll do it.

Comment: Reading the documentation for that plugin, it's explicitly trying to force you to code in a particular style. If you don't want to write your code that way, don't use the plugin I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [with-lifecycle](https://github.com/deepsweet/hocs/tree/master/packages/with-lifecycle) HOC which was written exactly for this purpose. Your example:

```js
import withLifecycle from '@hocs/with-lifecycle';

const enhance = compose(
    withLifecycle({
        onWillMount(props) {
            console.log(props);
        },
    }),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to access `props` without using `this` keyword in `lifecycle`. 
If you frequently have the same feature need to use lifecycle methods, you can implement your own HOC, still have to use `this`, but outside that yout don't have to write `this`, like [`recompose/shouldUpdate`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/src/packages/recompose/shouldUpdate.js).